# Bouncing ball in Pong against the wall and the paddle

Tags: python, pygame, pong

Hi y'all I'm very new to python and I'm struggling so bad trying to detect the walls(the edges of the screen) and make my ball in pong to bounce when they hit the wall. I've searched for how to but most people used turtle or some other thing that I cannot use so it didn't help that much. I get the algorithm of how to detect the wall but just don't know how to write code correctly. Here's my code below and I'd appreciate it very much if anyone can give me any idea on how to write code for this.

This is the exact error message I keep getting from the line 62.
error message:

> ```
> builtins.AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'get_rect'
> line 62 -> self.ballrect = self.ball.get_rect()
> ```

and here's the full code

```
import pygame
from random import randint


# User-defined functions

def main():
   # initialize all pygame modules (some need initialization)
   pygame.init()
   # create a pygame display window
   pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
   # set the title of the display window
   pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')   
   # get the display surface
   w_surface = pygame.display.get_surface() 
   # create a game object
   game = Game(w_surface)
   # start the main game loop by calling the play method on the game object
   game.play() 
   # quit pygame and clean up the pygame window
   pygame.quit() 


# User-defined classes

class Game:
   # An object in this class represents a complete game.

   def __init__(self, surface):
      # Initialize a Game.
      # - self is the Game to initialize
      # - surface is the display window surface object

      # === objects that are part of every game that we will discuss
      self.surface = surface
      self.bg_color = pygame.Color('black')

      self.FPS = 60
      self.game_Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
      self.close_clicked = False
      self.continue_game = True

      # === game specific objects    
      self.ball = Ball('white', 5, [250, 200], [1, 2], self.surface)
      self.max_frames = 150
      self.frame_counter = 0

   def play(self):
      # Play the game until the player presses the close box.
      # - self is the Game that should be continued or not.

      while not self.close_clicked:  # until player clicks close box
         # play frame
         self.handle_events()         
         self.draw()   
         self.ballrect = self.ball.get_rect()
         self.ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
         if self.ballrect.left < 0 or self.ballrect.right > 500:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]
         if self.ballrect.top < 0 or self.ballrect.bottom > 400:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]          
         if self.continue_game:
            self.update()
            self.decide_continue()
         self.game_Clock.tick(self.FPS) # run at most with FPS Frames Per Second 



   def handle_events(self):
      # Handle each user event by changing the game state appropriately.
      # - self is the Game whose events will be handled

      events = pygame.event.get()
      for event in events:
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.close_clicked = True

   def draw(self):
      # Draw all game objects.
      # - self is the Game to draw

      self.surface.fill(self.bg_color) # clear the display surface first
      pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 255, 255), (75, 190, 5, 20))
      pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 255, 255), (420, 190, 5, 20))       
      self.ball.draw()
      pygame.display.update() # make the updated surface appear on the display


   def update(self):
      # Update the game objects for the next frame.
      # - self is the Game to update

      self.ball.move()
      self.frame_counter += self.frame_counter 




   def decide_continue(self):
      # Check and remember if the game should continue
      # - self is the Game to check

      if self.frame_counter > self.max_frames:
         self.continue_game = False


class Ball:
   # An object in this class represents a Dot that moves 

   def __init__(self, ball_color, ball_radius, ball_center, ball_velocity, 
                surface):
      # Initialize a Dot.
      # - self is the Dot to initialize
      # - color is the pygame.Color of the dot
      # - center is a list containing the x and y int
      #   coords of the center of the dot
      # - radius is the int pixel radius of the dot
      # - velocity is a list containing the x and y components
      # - surface is the window's pygame.Surface object

      self.color = pygame.Color(ball_color)
      self.radius = ball_radius
      self.center = ball_center
      self.velocity = ball_velocity
      self.surface = surface



   def move(self):
      # Change the location of the Dot by adding the corresponding 
      # speed values to the x and y coordinate of its center
      # - self is the Dot

      for i in range(0,2):
         self.center[i] = (self.center[i] + self.velocity[i])
   def update(self):
      self.rect.x += self.velocity[0]
      self.rect.y += self.velocity[1]

   def bounce(self):
      self.velocity[0] = -self.velocity[0]
      self.velocity[1] = randint(-8,8)


   def draw(self):
      # Draw the dot on the surface
      # - self is the Dot

      pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.color, self.center, self.radius)






main()
```

Comment: The error is saying that you are trying to do the method `get_rect` on the class object `Ball` which doesn't have that method. If you look at your `class Ball` code it is right, that method doesn't exist. Is that supposed to be a pygame internal method or did you forget that you haven't written it yet?

Comment: I haven't copied anything except for the ballrect thing and everything else is from sample code I've got from my course I just added paddle and that ball rect thing to make it bounce. And what makes me so confused is that ballrect code is from pygame document and from example in there, it was working without anything additional to make it work. Like I looked through all the lines but anything in there except for that was just drawing ball and that was basically all which made me think it''s okay to use it right away.

Comment: get_rect()
get the rectangular area of the Surface
get_rect(**kwargs) -> Rect
Returns a new rectangle covering the entire surface. This rectangle will always start at (0, 0) with a width and height the same size as the image.

You can pass keyword argument values to this function. These named values will be applied to the attributes of the Rect before it is returned. An example would be mysurf.get_rect(center=(100, 100)) to create a rectangle for the Surface centered at a given position.

Comment: This is what I got from pygame document...

Comment: @YerimJung But `self.ball` is a `Ball` object rather than a `pygame.Surface` object. So of course `get_rect()` is not defined on `self.ball`. Furthermore `self.rect` respectively `speed` is used, but never defined in your code. This indicates that you've copied some code from different sources.

Comment: Yeah that speed thing and get_rect are from the same source from pygame that I mentioned above and that's the only source I used except for the original sample code I need to use which is from my course. I now get why it's not defined on it. Would you mind give some hint about how can I solve it too? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Ball class needs a rect attribute.

```
class Ball:
   # An object in this class represents a Dot that moves 

   def __init__(self, ball_color, ball_radius, ball_center, ball_velocity, 
                surface):
      # Initialize a Dot.
      # - self is the Dot to initialize
      # - color is the pygame.Color of the dot
      # - center is a list containing the x and y int
      #   coords of the center of the dot
      # - radius is the int pixel radius of the dot
      # - velocity is a list containing the x and y components
      # - surface is the window's pygame.Surface object

      self.color = pygame.Color(ball_color)
      self.radius = ball_radius
      self.center = ball_center
      self.velocity = ball_velocity
      self.surface = surface

      # create a Rect with width and height equal to radius,
      # then place it at the center of the ball
      self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.radius, self.radius)
      self.rect.center = self.center
```

Also, in update you need to again set the `self.rect.center` to the `self.center`, otherwise it will just stay in place. 
Or you get rid of the `self.center` altogether and just use `self.rect.center` since this is redundant information.